# 'Matching' Correspondence in R

Tags: r, match

In my "dataset1", I have a sort of dictionary, where each code corresponds to a state. In my second dataset, "dataset2", I would like to match the code to the proper state. I would appreciate a generalizable, vectorised solution.

Inputs:

```
dataset1               

 V1         V2
001   'State1'
005   'State2'
011   'State3'
011   'State3'
005   'State2'
dataset2

 V1
011
001
011
005
```

Desired output:

```
011   'State3'
001   'State1'
011   'State3'
005   'State2'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `R` `merge` function:

```
result <- merge(unique(dataset1), dataset2, by = "V1", all.x=FALSE, all.y=TRUE)

> result
   V1     V2
1 001 State1
2 005 State2
3 011 State3
4 011 State3
```

This will include all States from `dataset2` but will only include **unique** States from `dataset1` if they appear in `dataset2`.

Comment: I would highly recommend to use `TRUE` and `FALSE` rather than `T` and `F`. See what happens when `F = 1` and `T = "oups"` for example.

Comment: Is it the case that `T` can be a variable but `TRUE` cannot?

Comment: I learn something new every day I visit this site, and today was no exception ^ ^.

Comment: So I'm having problems with the merge command when my initial 'rulebook' has multiple entries. For example, suppose Dataset 1 contained another line with 011 'State3'. When I merge, I get an output that has more rows than the total rows in Dataset 2.

Comment: Please update your question with the exact type of join you want to do, and the expected output.

Comment: I have updated the question. The expected output is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `match`. Note that for multiple entries in `dataset1`, `match` will use the first one encountered.

```
dataset3 <- data.frame(V1=dataset2$V1, 
                       V2=as.character(dataset1$V2[match(x = dataset2$V1, 
                                                         table = dataset1$V1)]))
```

And to have the exact formatting:

```
cat(sprintf("%003.0f  '%s'\n", ds3$V1, ds3$V2))
# 011  'State3'
# 001  'State1'
# 011  'State3'
# 005  'State2'
```